# Jquery Datepicker - prevent select in range unavailable dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers (From date, to date) or when a people arive at my hotel and when he leaves. What i want to achieve is not to let the user select a range that includes unavailable dates.

**For example:**

Today is 13.02.2015, a people want to reserve from 15.02.2015 to 23.02.2015 but the dates 19-02-2015, 20-02-2015 are already reserved. So i want to disable all the fields starting from 19.02.2015 meaning that he can select only from 15.02.2015 to 18.02.2015. It depends on what date he picks and he can book only to the first unavailable date, not next to that.

How can I achieve this?

***This is my html code:***

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

***This is the javascript code***

```
var unavailableDates = ["19-2-2015", "20-2-2015", "23-2-2015", "24-2-2015"]

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my [jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/jhupcm1L/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

I have created a function which convert string to Date

```
function compareDate(str1, sep){
var dt1   = parseInt(str1.split(sep)[0], 10);
var mon1  = parseInt(str1.split(sep)[1], 10);
var yr1   = parseInt(str1.split(sep)[2], 10);
var date1 = new Date(yr1, mon1-1, dt1);
return date1;
}
```

Next I have created a function which gives the maxDate for `#to` Smartly.

```
function setMaxDate()
{
    var date = $("#from").val();
    for(var i=0; i<unavailableDates.length; i++)
    {
    if(compareDate(date, "/")<compareDate(unavailableDates[i], "-")) 
        return compareDate(unavailableDates[i], "-");
    }
    return null;
}
```

and doing some modifications in datepicker init

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", setMaxDate() ); // Added This
        }
    });

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        maxDate: setMaxDate(),    // Added This
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

And it worked.. Here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhupcm1L/4/)

Comment: Hey, Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Just a suggestion use the seperator `/` instead of `-` in `unavailableDates ` so as not to complicate.

Comment: Why did you used mon1-1 insted of mon1?

Comment: On which line of fiddle?

Comment: var date1 = new Date(yr1, mon1-1, dt1);

Comment: Because in `JS` 0=January, 1=Feb, But in datepicker it is human friendly i.e. 1=January, 2=Feb

Comment: Thanks. By the way, your example works but it needs a correction, I will edit it.

Comment: alert(parseInt('08')); shows a diferent value in mozilla (8) and a diferent value in safari (0). and because of this , in safari i recived a non valid date from the compareDate function. we had to use : parseInt(str1.split(sep)[1], 10);